# Sub menu not auto adding class on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page and I am trying to auto set the active link on the sub menu. I have the same code working on my header for the main navigation but the sub navigation is not working correctly. I have alerted the value of the url to make sure its correct and it is but its not even getting into the .each loop.

Here is the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Link to CSS stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- jQuery Hosted Library Link -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery Scripts -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            // Get url and set navigation to the corresponding active page
            $(function(){
                // Set active main nav tab
                var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

                if(pgurl.indexOf('?') > -1){
                    pgurl = pgurl.substring(0, pgurl.indexOf('?'));
                }

                if(pgurl.indexOf('#') > -1){
                    pgurl = pgurl.substring(0, pgurl.indexOf('#'));
                }

                $("#nav-main ul li a").each(function(){
                      if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
                      $(this).addClass("a-active");
                 });

                 resizeDiv();

                 // Resize the sections to fit to the window height
                 function resizeDiv(){
                     vph = $(window).height();
                     vph = vph - 111;
                     $('#left-column').css({'min-height': vph});
                     $('#right-column').css({'min-height': vph});
                 }

                 // Import correct side nav
                 var side = pgurl.substring(0, pgurl.indexOf('.php'));

                 $.ajax({
                    url: "include/nav-side-"+side+".php", success: function(result){
                        $('#nav-side').html(result);
                        }, error: function (){
                            $('#nav-side').html("<p>An error has occurred importing the navigation.</p>");
                        }
                 });

                 // Set active sub nav listing
                 var suburl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

                 if(suburl.indexOf('#') > -1){
                     suburl = suburl.substring(0, suburl.indexOf('#'));
                 }

                 $("#nav-side ul li a").each(function(){
                      if($(this).attr("href") == suburl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
                      $(this).addClass("a-active");
                 });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <title>Senneca Portal | Adminstration Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once("include/header.php"); ?>
    <section id="content">
        <section id="left-column">
            <img id="profile-img" src=""/>
            <nav id="nav-side"></nav>
        </section>
        <section id="right-column">
            <div id="content-header">
                <button id="create">Add <?php echo $pageName; ?></button>
                <h2><?php echo $pageName; ?></h2>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my imported navigation uls for the sub navigation.

```
    <ul>
    <p class="p-nav-side-title">Admin Controls</p>
    <li><a href="admin.php">Websites</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.php?page=products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.php?page=library">Library</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.php?page=users">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

For some reason though this is not even making it to the second .each loop for the nav-side element.

I believe it is due to the fact its ajaxed into the page on load. How can I get this to work correctly on import?

Comment: Move the stuff after the AJAX call into the success function of the AJAX call.

Comment: That worked. I thought I had tried that before. Why does that work but it doesnt work when I have the jQuery outside and after the ajax call? Wouldn't it still be there after the ajax call?

Comment: No, the way JavaScript works is that the AJAX line is called, and JavaScript just keeps on going. It doesn't wait for the AJAX to finish. That is what the success/complete/fail functions are for. To process code after the AJAX response is received.

Comment: Ohhh I gotcha I was thinking the rest wouldnt have been implemented until after the call. That makes sense now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, this is what the first A in AJAX is all about..."asynchronous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "// Set active sub nav listing" part is not waiting for the ajax to finish, so it's being executed before the imported side nav is even loaded.

try this:

```
            $.ajax({
                        url : "include/nav-side-" + side + ".php",
                        success : function(result) {
                            $('#nav-side').html(result);

                            // Set active sub nav listing
                            var suburl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                            if (suburl.indexOf('#') > -1) {
                                suburl = suburl.substring(0, suburl.indexOf('#'));
                            }

                            $("#nav-side ul li a").each(function() {
                                if ($(this).attr("href") == suburl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
                                    $(this).addClass("a-active");
                            });

                        },
                        error : function() {
                            $('#nav-side').html("<p>An error has occurred importing the navigation.</p>");
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
```